# selecting html editor in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: html, aptana, aptana3

I am very new to this. I just bought one of those "html for dummies" books. It states "in preferences expand the APTANA link and select html editor." I'm on a MAC and running Aptana Studio 3. Under that tab, there is no html editor option, just browsers terminal and theme.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what tab you're talking about, but if you tgo to `Window`->`Preferences` you're presented with the preferences dialog, which should have an expandable tree list of pages in the left pane and the actual preferences in the content pane on the right.

If you expand the `Aptana Studio` item in the list pane, it contains the subpages:

- Content Assist
- Editors
- Find Bar
- Formatter
- JavaScript Debug
- Remote
- Spelling
- Tasks
- Terminal
- Themes
- Troubleshooting
- Validation
- Webservers

And if you expand the `Editors`, you'll see a bunch of different languages, including HTML.